# importImages.php is not moving all the files into the correct subdirectory

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

We have a wiki that was brought back from the dead using a torrent image archive of 32gb+ (that's compressed).

We ran importImages. That created sub-directories, probably from the image paths of the wiki articles.

Well, we have a lot of images not loading correctly (white space).

Turns out the importImages did not move all the images into their correct subdirecotires.

When you look up the image, it will have the expected sub directory i.e. images/1/1a/hello.jpg

But, the actual file is still in images/hello.jpg.

If you try to reupload the image using the single file uploader, it gives you an overwrite warning, ignoring this warning corrects the image, and stores it in the right subdirectory. But we have 200k+ images, and you cannot overwrite images using uploadWizard.

Is there a way to fix this? A parameter we can run, or a way to set all image paths to use just .../images/?

We are using version 1.35.1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, [`$wgHashedUploadDirectory`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgHashedUploadDirectory) or [`$wgLocalFileRepo`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgLocalFileRepo) is not set correctly on `LocalSettings.php`. If this is not the case, try to launch `importImages.php` with `--overwrite` option.

Comment: I had the selfsame thought.  I talked to my SysOps and said the same thing, and told him to rerun it with overwrite.